# How to find a sequence that comes from an other table, MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sequence

I have 2 tables in mysql database. This first is the results and the second is the testrun table. The results table contains data of tests and the testrun table contains what test need to be tested. 
I need to know if the sequence that you can find in testrun exists in results and also result can't be 0 in that sequence.

```
**testrun**
    +---------+------------+----------+----------------+
    | BoardId | TestSpecId | sequence | ExecutionOrder |
    +---------+------------+----------+----------------+
    |    9000 |          1 |      400 |              1 |
    |    9000 |          1 |      401 |              2 |
    |    9000 |          2 |        4 |              1 |
    |    9000 |          2 |        2 |              2 |
    |    9000 |          2 |        3 |              3 |
    |    9000 |          2 |        1 |              4 |
    |    9001 |          1 |      401 |              1 |
    |    9001 |          1 |      403 |              2 |
    |    9001 |          1 |      404 |              3 |
    |    9001 |          2 |        5 |              1 |
    |    9001 |          2 |        2 |              2 |
    |    9001 |          2 |        3 |              3 |
    |    9001 |          2 |        1 |              4 |
    |    9001 |          2 |        4 |              5 |
    +---------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

```
**results**
+---------+--------+------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
| BoardId | Result | ProductionLinkId | TestSpecId | sequence | ExecutionOrder |
+---------+--------+------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
|    9000 |      1 |              200 |          1 |      400 |              1 |
|    9000 |      1 |              200 |          1 |      401 |              2 |
      Sequence Passed
|    9000 |      1 |              200 |          2 |        4 |              1 |
|    9000 |      1 |              200 |          2 |        2 |              2 |
|    9000 |      1 |              200 |          2 |        3 |              3 |
       Missing a value in sequence: sequence failed
|    9001 |      1 |              300 |          1 |      401 |              1 |
|    9001 |      1 |              300 |          1 |      403 |              2 |
|    9001 |      1 |              300 |          1 |      404 |              3 |
      Sequence passed
|    9001 |      1 |              300 |          2 |        5 |              1 |
|    9001 |      1 |              300 |          2 |        2 |              2 |
|    9001 |      1 |              300 |          2 |        3 |              3 |
|    9001 |  **0** |              300 |          2 |        1 |              4 |
|    9001 |      1 |              300 |          2 |        4 |              5 |
       Sequence contains 0: sequence failed
|    9001 |      1 |              400 |          1 |      401 |              1 |
|    9001 |      1 |              400 |          1 |      403 |              2 |
|    9001 |      1 |              400 |          1 |      404 |              3 |
      Sequence passed
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          1 |      401 |              1 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          1 |      403 |              2 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          1 |      404 |              3 |
      Sequence passed
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          2 |        5 |              1 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          2 |        2 |              2 |
|    9001 |  **0** |              500 |          2 |        3 |              3 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          2 |        5 |              1 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          2 |        2 |              2 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          2 |        3 |              3 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          2 |        1 |              4 |
|    9001 |      1 |              500 |          2 |        4 |              5 |
      Sequence passed because sequence comes after each other and its all 1
+---------+--------+------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

The results that we need to get with a sql query is the following

```
+---------+------------------+------------+---------+
| BoardId | ProductionLinkId | TestSpecId | Results |
+---------+------------------+------------+---------+
|    9000 |              200 |          1 |       1 |
|    9000 |              200 |          2 |       0 |
|    9001 |              300 |          1 |       1 |
|    9001 |              300 |          2 |       0 |
|    9001 |              400 |          1 |       1 |
|    9001 |              500 |          1 |       1 |
|    9001 |              500 |          2 |       1 |
+---------+------------------+------------+---------+
```

So per Specific boardId, specific ProductionLinkId and specific TestSpecId, needs a result.

```
SELECT * FROM testrun,results where 
testrun.BoardId = results.boardId 
and testrun.TestSpecId = results.TestSpecId 
and testrun.SequenceId = results.sequenceId
```

**Update with fiddle:** [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kB922r4wrkYW7f4ckPKdUu/2)

```
select * from (select * from results where result = 1) as res
    left outer join (SELECT * FROM testrun) as run on res.BoardId = run.boardId and res.TestSpecId = run.TestSpecId and res.SequenceId = run.sequenceId
union
select * from (select * from results where result = 1) as res
    right outer join (SELECT * FROM testrun) as run on res.BoardId = run.boardId and res.TestSpecId = run.TestSpecId and res.SequenceId = run.sequenceId 
order by ProductionLinkId
```

**View on fiddle:** [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/92BYp4TM5Dj3zp9RxDYANz/0)
Here you get which value are missing but you do not now from which ProductionLinkId it comes from and if there is a correct sequence with all test needed to run. 
This is a example file with more data:
[Example SQL file](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgKeKaO_R-pEigsmh_3k00fbClec)

After long searching have I finally found it.

```
SELECT res.BoardId, res.ProductionLinkId, res.TestSpecId, res.execu, spec.exec, if(res.execu LIKE CONCAT('%',spec.exec,'%'),1,0) FROM
    (SELECT BoardId, TestSpecId, group_concat(ExecutionOrder order by ExecutionOrder) as exec FROM testrun group by BoardId, TestSpecId) as spec
inner join
    (SELECT BoardId, ProductionLinkId, TestSpecId, group_concat(ExecutionOrder order by resultId) as execu FROM (SELECT * FROM results where result = 1) as resultGrpSpec group by BoardId, ProductionLinkId, TestSpecId) as res
on spec.BoardId = res.BoardId and spec.TestSpecId = res.TestSpecId
```

**View on fiddle:** [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f1F83EsVDMaLGLyt9s915d/0)

Comment: Hi stevenvano. Can you please update your question with the MySQL query you've tested? thanks

Comment: From your query, which table is `runover9000withexecute1` and which is `dataover90001` in your data example above? If I have to guess, `runover9000withexecute1` is testrun table and `dataover90001` is results table. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but it has the same intention, so I need to find a certain sequence for a specific boardId, ProductionLinkId, TestSpecId. And I want to now if it contains that sequence. How to find a sequence is the problem I can't find. - thanks in advance

Comment: I can't tell what problem you have. I tested your sample data (although it does not include any productionlinkid values), and when I try your current SQL query I do get rows for BoardId=9000, TestSpecId=10100, SequenceId in(3,4), ExecutionOrder in(5,6). But the `result = 1` for these rows, given your test data. I think you need to create an example to demonstrate your problem more clearly.

Comment: So what I need to know is how to find a sequence like 2, 3, 4,5, 7 that comes from 'testrun' and exists in 'Results'specified for every productionLinkId and TestSpecId. If you have for example a productionlinkid 200 with a sequence of 2, 2, 3, 5, 7 than need this to be a fail. If you find a sequence of 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 than need htis to be a pass.